# "Navigate Up" issues in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

If I am on page

```
http://mysite.com/first/second/third/Wiki/pages/home.aspx
```

and click the Navigate Up button I can see the following hierarchy (whis is correct):

```
Home - first - second - third - Wiki
```

But if I navigate up one step to

```
http://mysite.com/first/second/third/SitePages/Home.aspx
```

and click the Navigate Up button again the first subsite is not showing up.

```
Home - second - third - Home
```

I set the navigation settings to be identical on both sites but still the same issue/error.

How can I fix this?

Cheers

Comment: What is the url for the page that is showing incorrect navigation?

Comment: the second url in the question... it shows correct navigation on the top nav bar but not when I click the button Navigate Up, it is skipping one level in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

A few things you can try....

- In your masterpage / page layout, find your **SiteMapPath** control. This has a property called **ParentLevelsDisplayed**. If you set it to **-1** (the default) it should show all parent sites in the breadcrumb. Also, make sure that the **SiteMapProvider** is the same for both controls on both pages.
- In your */second* subsite, check whether or not the global navigation is set to inherit from its parent. This setting will affect how the breadcrumb is displayed, more on this [[here]](http://www.novolocus.com/2008/02/21/what-the-heck-is-going-on-with-sharepoint-breadcrumbs/).
- Third (and this only applies to publishing sites), open the page layout that your Home.aspx page is referencing. Search for **PlaceHolderTitleBreadcrumb**. Lots of the OOTB layouts override this placeholder and construct their own breadcrumb. There is a great list [[here]](http://www.heathersolomon.com/blog/archive/2008/08/13/SharePoint-Breadcrumbs--Sample-of-differences-chart-of-uses-and.aspx) of all the layouts and their individual breadcrumb settings.

Hopefully this helps!